# Foreach with custom index PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Hi :) I have this array in PHP.

```
Array ( [99] => 5 [2] => 5 [45] => 4 [4] => 3 [84] => 1 [6] => 3 )
```

I want to cicle this array in order to *build* a SQL query.

The query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO table (index, value) VALUES (99, 5), (2, 5), (45, 4), (4, 3), (84, 1), (6, 3);
```

I'm looking for a PHP *for* or *foreach* cicle, in order to have inside my query not only the value of the elements, but also the originary index (that is not 0, 1, 2..).

Thanks! 
Have a nice day! :)

**SOLUTION**

```
foreach ($obt as $key => $value) {
     echo "$key -> $value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo"Key: {$key}";
    echo"Val: {$value}";
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: No this will not help completely. It's a help but not the full-fledge solution

Comment: Thank you all! This is the easiest and fastest way! Thanks again!

Comment: @AlivetoDie Why not? Because I haven't provided how he can get the desierd query out of it? I assume that he knows some PHP and should be able to do this by his own, and as it seems, he did. Also he asked for a foreach loop to have key & values. He haven't asked directly to give him a full solution to also create the query.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a *foreach*:

```
$arr = [99 => 5, 2 => 4];

$valuePairs = [];

foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    $valuePairs[] = sprintf('(%u, %u)', $index, $value);
}

$values = implode(', ', $valuePairs);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (index, value) VALUES $values;";

echo $sql;
```

This will get you your desired result:

```
INSERT INTO table (index, value) VALUES (99, 5), (2, 4);
```

I'm assuming you always have numbers in your array. You may also want to check that the input array is not empty before using this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php array functions:

```
$ins = implode(', ', array_map(function ($k, $v) {
        return "({$k},{$v})";
    }, array_keys($arr), array_values($arr)));

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (index, value) VALUES {$ins};"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is `foreach()` loop with `implode()`

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = '(' . $key . ', ' . $value . ')';
}
$values = implode(', ', $values) . ';';

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (index, value) VALUES $values";
```